# How to made a forecast in R?

Tags: sql-server, r, powerbi

I have a dataset of money paid for contracts within a year quarter with 17 years of history. 
I want to plot a forecast for upcoming quarters.

I've tried:

```
library(forecast)

# group dataset
dataset <- aggregate(Paid Amount ~ Calendar Year Qtr, data = dataset, FUN= sum)

# create a time series based on yer qrt
ts <- ts(dataset$Paid Amount, frequency=7)

# pull out the seasonal, trend, and irregular components from the time series (train the forecast model)
decom <- stl(ts, s.window = "periodic")

# predict the next 2 qrt
pred <- forecast(decom, h = 2)

# plot the predicted values
plot(pred)
```

I'm running it in Power BI from my ralational database (SQL). I've used the same script with minor changes in frequency and predicted steps for plotting currency rates, however this one does not work.
Any help would be appreciated.

Sample data:

```
Calendar Year Qrt | Paid Amount
2000Q1            | 43 453 121
2000Q2            | 121 754 123
....
2017Q2            | 178 456 123
```

Comment: Your calendar year appears to be text, which is a really bad idea in SQL Server, or really any database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, it's NVARCHAR, but cannot be remapped.

Comment: Can I convert it into a number somehow? Eg 2001Q1 -> 2001-1